# quiero mostrar un mensaje js antes de 10 minutos de una columna type data-time php

Tags: php, javascript, html, date

reformulando mi pregunta anterior
estoy buscando que
me arroje los datops de toda la columna de fecha
y que solo alas que le resten 10 minutos a la hora actual que seria fecha de resolucion = -10 minutos
me arroje un script pero no eh podido encontrar la forma logica de hacerlo

```
$query5 = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, fecha_resolucion,'$now'-10) as minutos from ordenes ";
$deto = mysqli_query($link, $query5);

$date = new DateTime(); 
$date->modify('-10 minute'); 
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
var_dump($deto);
 if($deto >= $date){
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Te quedan 10 minutos para cerrar tu orden" );
    window.location.href="index.php";
    </script>'; 
}
```

lo ejecute con mysql y si me muestra todos pero php no

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunas cosas por corregir, tanto en la lógica, como en el código:

**Requisito:** Obtener órdenes con fecha límite igual o inferior a 10 minutos, a partir del momento en que se hace la consulta.

**¿Qué hacer?**

- Tomar fecha actual
- Incrementar 10 minutos, que es el límite para cerrar órdenes
- Obtener órdenes con fecha límite menor a la calculada
- Para evitar que aparezcan registros muy antiguos (ya caducados), se pueden agregar otros filtros:

  - Fecha límite mayor o igual que la actual: `fecha_resolucion >= NOW()`
  - Estado de orden: Activa, inactiva, pendiente o la que aplique según tu sistema
  - ¿Usuario al que pertenecen las órdenes?

En PHP tienes otro error, que es querer acceder a los resultados de la consulta directamente desde `$deto`, pero la variable contiene solo un ID de recurso para acceso a resultados y debes recorrerlos con alguna de las funciones de lectura disponibles [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php), sugiero `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, que devuelve arreglo asociativo con `nombre_de_columna => valor`

```
$date = new DateTime(); 
$date->modify('+10 minute'); 
$maxDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


$query5 = "SELECT * FROM ordenes WHERE fecha_resolucion <= '$maxDate'";
$deto = mysqli_query($link, $query5);

// No puedes acceder a los resultados con $deto... tienes que recorrer uno a uno
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($deto)) {
    echo $row['fecha_resolucion'];
}
```

Teniendo la consulta filtrada correctamente, ya no es necesario realizar comparaciones en PHP, simplemente mostrar los mensajes que correspondan.

Comment: gracias me sirvio bastate 
y disculpa para sacar el script a los 10 minutos que vaya a vencer por ejemplo
 if($deto == -10){
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Te quedan 10 minutos para cerrar tú orden" );
    </script>'; 
}